# Azure Dev Ops Pipeline task (Load Runner Enterpri

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-pipelines, loadrunner

I am using Azure Dev Ops to create a pipeline that triggers a test in Load Runner Enterprise. My task is to parse the RunID (circled in red) out of the raw log to use for another process. The script I have created successfully parses out the RunID but the issue I am having is I can not find the raw log to reference in my Powershell script. How would I go about finding the information shown and referencing it in my Powershell script?

LoadRunnerOutputLog:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The script I have created successfully parses out the RunID but the issue I am having is I can not find the raw log to reference in my Powershell script.

As per the `LoadRunner Enterprise Test` task [doc](https://github.com/MicroFocus/Performance-Center-TFS-Plugin/wiki), it will generate the report to your agent machine. It's Report.zip and Report.html from your log screenshot.

You can add a new task after test task, extract the `RunID` value from report, set it as varibale and invoke it in next powershell task.

How to set variable, please refer to official doc [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/set-variables-scripts?view=azure-devops&tabs=bash#set-an-output-variable-for-use-in-the-same-job).

You can use `Extract files` task to extract content from zip and then you can parse the value of 'RunID'.

BTW, it's recommended to add variable "system.debug" as `true` in your pipeline, check if `RunID` is set as environment value, if it is, you can directly invoke it in next powershell task.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by, "raw log?"  Most of the time the output log is disables during tests as constantly writing to the disk acts like a drag anchor behind a speedboat